# What happens if I put my DC voltage source AFTER the diode instead of before?

Tags: diodes, voltage-measurement, practical

I have a homework question on diodes, in which I have to calculate the Voltages across the diodes. All the questions I have encountered thus far have had the DC source BEFORE the diode. This one has the DC source AFTER the diode.

We have to make use of the Practical Diode Model in our reasoning. This is the only information they gave us:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fZx0TY.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have looked at other questions and websites, but most of them only explain reverse bias situations, not switching the diode and the source around. Does it actually make a difference? If so, why? Or is it just a way to confuse us?

Comment: It doesn't make a difference, the diode is forward biased and conducting, you can calculate the voltage drop across it. Not to confuse you, but to make you think. Real-life problems don't always follow the perfect textbook question.

Comment: The only implication is that you will not have same ground as may be in other systems, connected to same power source. Why would you want such thing?

Comment: @SteveG you might as well flesh that out and post as an answer, otherwise it'll just stick around as unanswered

Comment: Both official responses answer the question really well. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as the positive terminal of the battery is connected to the P-type material (behind the SYMBOL of the diode) and negative terminal of the battery is connected to the N-type material (front of the SYMBOL of diode) the diode remains forward biased and current will flow. So it does not matter battery is before or after the diode. What matters is the polarity to which the diode is connected.

Answer (score 5):

It doesn't make a difference, the diode is forward biased and conducting, you can calculate the voltage drop across it.

It's not a way to confuse you, but to make you think. Real-life problems don't always follow the perfect textbook question.